# Phrase for describing a cable without a connector at the end

Tags: terminology

I've been translating a truck scale description in a business offer letter, and the specification table there, listing the five parts comprising the prospective order, says on line five:

> Cable for connecting the load cell to the weighing terminal, **bare end**. Length: 30m.

In the Russian original, the phrase "открытый конец" (literally "open end") most likely means that the cable has no connector attached to it. It probably comes out of the load cell, and then is cut at this length, 30m. The Buyer can attach the necessary connector.

What would be a naturally-looking phrase for describing the same "bare end" in a similar English document?

([Also asked on ELL SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93187/phrase-for-describing-a-cable-without-a-connector-at-the-end))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that 'bare end' gets the meaning across pretty well. Although in the context of a specification I would be tempted to spell out precisely that the cable is not supplied with a connector or terminator as a footnote eg :

> Cable for connecting the load cell to the weighing terminal, bare end.
>   Length: 30m.*
>
> *Cables are supplied as cut and will require a suitable connector to be fitted to the free end before use.

I would also add that, from the perspective of a customer,  I would look for an indication that a braided cable has been at least prepared in some way that it won't be frayed or unravelling when I receive it.

Also you don't specify whether this is an electrical/data cable or a load bearing one (from the fact that it comes off a load cell I've assumed that it is something like a winch cable) Obviously if it's something exotic or specialized like oilfield wire-line or HT power transmission that's a whole different matter.

Comment: I've also heard the term "pigtail" used to describe a cable terminating with bare wires instead of a connector.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is an electrical cable, not a mechanical cable. The "load cell" is the part that actually measures the load, and presumably the "weighing terminal" is the electronics that displays the measurements to the operator -  possibly inside a building, to protect the electronics and the operator from the weather etc, while the actual truck weighing mechanism may be some distance away outside. Connecting the load cell to something with 30m of wire rope doesn't seem like a reasonable design for a "truck scale."

"Bare end" or "bare ended" is understandable, but a more formal general term would be **unterminated.**

There are more specific terms for particular forms of "unterminated" wire and cable - see the "wire termination options" and "cable termination options" here: http://www.dsmt.com/resources/termination-options/

Most of those options only apply to a cable that is already cut to the correct length, and has been prepared ready to connect to something - but that doesn't seem to be the situation that you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one conductor in the cable, the term 'flying leads' is often used.